# Using arrays not attached to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to use an array without actually assigning it to a variable? e.g.

```
for (int numb: {1,2,3,4,5,6}){
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

or

```
public class TestArrays{
   public static void doStuff(double[] doubles){
       //doStuff
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
       doStuff({1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
   }
}
```

Because when I try it now I get compilation problems as if the compiler isn't recognizing the entity as an array.

Comment: While we can diagnose this without it; in general it is best to quote what the compiler actually prints rather than say "I get compilation problems", there is useful information in there

Answer (score 5):

Yes, like this:

```
for (int number : new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

or

```
doStuff(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider instead using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) for passing a variable number of parameters

```
public static void doStuff(double... doubles){
       //doStuff
}
```

and call

```
doStuff(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

You could use the varargs of [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) for the `for` loop

```
for (int number: Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6)) {
   System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, this property extends beyond just primitive arrays. Because in Java, arrays are also objects, you can do this with any object.

```
doStuff(new String("Dave"));
doStuff(new Car("Ford"));
```

This is called an anonymous object, and makes for some nice code from time to time, although abuse tends to lead to pretty unreadable code. Use wisely!

Comment: I dislike the term "anonymous object" (which isn't an official term as far as I'm aware) - it suggests that otherwise, objects have names... they don't. *Variables* have names; objects don't.

Comment: Jesus, the Skeet has spoken. I have some university lecturers to correct, it seems!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

instead of just

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```